# Apache POI throws exception while reading xlsx file in Linux enviroment

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using the latest version of Apache POI at this moment which is 4.1.1. Every thing is working fine for xls file. Even for xlsx file in development environment Windows. But I am getting exception in live environment Red Hat Linux.

I have already searched for solutions mostly said to use proper xmlbeans dependency. I am using xml-beans-3.1.0.jar.

I am exporting the war file from eclipse and publishing in oracle web-logic 12c.

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:657)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:282)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:341)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:316)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:234)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:200)
        ...............................................................................
        ...............................................................................

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
        ... 181 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
        ... 187 more
```

Here is the full library list I have used:

```
activation-1.1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
axis.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-codec-1.13.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-collections4-4.4.jar
commons-compress-1.19.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-discovery.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.9.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
core-3.1.0.jar
curvesapi-1.06.jar
datatables-core-0.9.3.jar
datatables-jsp-0.9.3.jar
datatables-servlet2-0.9.3.jar
displaytag-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dynaHandlers.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
gson-2.6.2.jar
hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
iText-5.0.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.8.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.3.jar
jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
java-json.jar
javase-3.1.0.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar
javax.wsdl.jar
jaxrpc-api.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
jersey-client-1.9.jar
jersey-core-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jersey-multipart-1.9.jar
jersey-server-1.9.jar
jsch-0.1.53.jar
json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.0.6.jar
jta-1.1.jar
juli-6.0.18.jar
junit-4.10.jar
log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
log4j-web-2.3.jar
mail.jar
ognl-3.1.4.jar
ojdbc6.jar
opencsv-2.3.jar
org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar
org.apache.felix.main-4.0.3.jar
org.apache.felix.shell-1.4.3.jar
org.apache.felix.shell.tui-1.4.1.jar
org.osgi.compendium-4.0.0.jar
org.osgi.core-4.1.0.jar
oval-1.31.jar
plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-10.jar
plexus-utils-1.2.jar
poi-4.1.1.jar
poi-excelant-4.1.1.jar
poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar
poi-scratchpad-4.1.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
SMSClient.jar
spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
standard-1.0.6.jar
standard.jar
struts-menu-2.4.3.jar
struts2-core-2.5.jar
struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar
struts2-jquery-tree-plugin-3.7.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.5.jar
struts2-sitemesh-plugin-2.5.jar
tiles-api-3.0.5.jar
tiles-core-3.0.5.jar
tiles-jsp-3.0.5.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
velocity-1.4.jar
velocity-tools-view-1.0.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
xmlpserver.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.8.jar
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your classpath? Just to be sure there are really no conflicts in XMLBeans versions.

Comment: For sure this is not related with Linux or Windows environments. It is running in your Development environment and not in the server because of issues in your classpath. As you did not provide much more info, check how you are packaging your application. The issue is probably there. This is a classical case of "but it works on my machine!" ;)

Comment: I am exporting the war file from eclipse and publishing in oracle web-logic 12c. I have updated the issue with the library list I have used. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

I got around this error by setting this in weblogic.xml:

```
<container-descriptor>      
    <prefer-application-packages>
       <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>  
</container-descriptor>
```

Weblogic 12c has an old version(2.0) of XMLBeans!

Answer (score 1):

According to

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
```

I suspect your class `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions` came not really from `xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar` but from any other library which possibly includes an old version of `org.apache.xmlbeans.*`.

You could detect where the class came from using folowing code:

```
ClassLoader classloader =
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.class.getClassLoader();
java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource(
    "org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("XmlOptions came from " + path);
```

Comment: Thanks all. I checked and found that in the server its actually pointing to a different xmloptions class. I downgraded to poi 3.7 package. Though it is still pointing to the weblogic server jar. But solves my issue.